# Apportable wrong orientation

Tags: apportable

It looks like everything is going to work.. 
My game compiles and successfully creates a running android version.
It is just in the wrong orientation.  It show up in landscape when it should be portrait.

The Apportable Beta splash screen also shows up in landscape when it should be in portrait.

I correctly chose 1 and p when I first started.

Is there any way to get my game turned to portrait and the splash screen as well.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `info.plist` indicates that you only support portrait orientations.

Additionally, make sure that `info.plist` is present in `<you project>.approj/targets/<your target>/Release.final` under the `infoplists` key.